# If you save a pandas dataframe using 'to_json', and the index has a new label, is there a way to preserve that label name in the file?

Tags: python, pandas

Say that you set a column to an index using

`df = df.set_index('new_index')`

The index now has a label, which is the column label of the column that was converted into an index.

If you save it using

`df.to_json('file.json')`

The index doesn't have its old label.

Is there a way to preserve the new index label?

Reason:

I am working with very large files and to save space, I am eliminating the index. But I would like to the file to inherently give information about what that label actually is.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to overcome that, maybe not very pythonic but it works:

```
df_json  = (json.load(open('test.json', 'r')))

df = pd.DataFrame(df_json, index=df_json['units'].keys())

df.reset_index()
```

`'unit'` is the name of any column (since you didn't provide a sample) and `'test.json'` is the name of the JSON.

Found an easier way:

```
df.to_json('test.json', orient='split')
df = pd.read_json('test.json', orient='split')
```

When you use split it keeps the indices in a separate column, you can read futher in the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html) of read_json

Comment: Does this help you? @SantoshGupta7